# how to get nested data with pandas and request

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I'm going crazy trying to get data through an API call using request and pandas. It looks like it's nested data, but I cant get the data i need.

https://xorosoft.docs.apiary.io/#reference/sales-orders/get-sales-orders

above is the api documentation. I'm just trying to keep it simple and get the itemnumber and qtyremainingtoship, but i cant even figure out how to access the nested data. I'm trying to use DataFrame to get it, but am just lost. any help would be appreciated. i keep getting stuck at the 'Data' level.

```
type(json['Data'])
df = pd.DataFrame(['Data'])


df.explode('SoEstimateHeader')
df.explode('SoEstimateHeader')


  Cell In [64], line 1
    df.explode([0:])
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: are you able to share what code you  have already written and also what data you have received from the API endpoint already?

Comment: I've added in what i have. the code above is just what i have after getting a 200 response from the API call. I have tried many other ways to get the data, this is just what i have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the link to grab a sample response from the API documentation page you provided. From the code you provided it looks like you are already able to get the data and I'm assuming the you have it as a dictionary type already.

From what I can tell I don't think you should be using pandas, unless its some downstream requirement in the task you are doing. But to get the `ItemNumber` & `QtyRemainingToShip` you can use the code below.

```
# get the interesting part of the data out of the api response
data_list = json['Data']

#the data_list is only one element long, so grab the first element which is of type dictionary
data = data_list[0]
# the dictionary has two keys at the top level
so_estimate_header = data['SoEstimateHeader']

# similar to the data list the value associated with "SoEstimateItemLineArr" is of type list and has 1 element in it, so we grab the first & only element.
so_estimate_item_line_arr = data['SoEstimateItemLineArr'][0]

# now we can grab the pieces of information we're interested in out of the dictionary
qtyremainingtoship = so_estimate_item_line_arr["QtyRemainingToShip"]
itemnumber = so_estimate_item_line_arr["ItemNumber"]

print("QtyRemainingToShip: ", qtyremainingtoship)
print("ItemNumber: ", itemnumber)
```

#### Output

`QtyRemainingToShip:  1`

`ItemNumber:  BC`

###### Side Note

As a side note I wouldn't name any variables `json` because thats also the name of a popular library in python for parsing json, so that will be confusing to future readers and will clash with the name if you end up having to import the `json` library.